# How to determine which port ASP.NET Core 2 is listening on when a dynamic port (0) was specified

Tags: kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-2.0

I've got an ASP.NET Core 2.0 app which I intend to run as a stand-alone application. The app should start up and bind to an available port. To achieve this I configure the WebHostBuilder to listen on "http://127.0.0.1:0" and to use the Kestrel server. Once the web host starts listening I want to save the url with the actual port in a file. I want to do this as early as possible, since another application will read the file to interact with my app.

How can I determine the port the web host is listening on?

Answer (score 16):

You can achive it in Startup class in method Configure. You can get port from ServerAddressesFeature

Here is an example of code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
     var serverAddressesFeature = app.ServerFeatures.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>();

     loggerFactory.AddFile("logs/myfile-{Date}.txt", minimumLevel: LogLevel.Information, isJson: false);

     logger.LogInformation("Listening on the following addresses: " + string.Join(", ", serverAddressesFeature.Addresses));
}
```

Comment: There are 0 addresses, any ideas why?

Comment: Are you sure @jjxtra?
It is enumerator so you have to do something like this:



`foreach (var address in serverAddressesFeature.Addresses)
        Console.WriteLine(address.ToString());
`

Comment: FYI, this unfortunately does not seem to pick up url prefixes when hosting via Http.Sys.

Comment: seems like you need to run the webserver first or else you'll get no addresses

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `Start()` method instead of `Run()` to access `IServerAddressesFeature` at the right moment:

```
IWebHost webHost = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel(options => 
         options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 0)) // dynamic port
    .Build();

webHost.Start();

string address = webHost.ServerFeatures
    .Get<IServerAddressesFeature>()
    .Addresses
    .First();
int port = int.Parse(address.Split(':').Last());

webHost.WaitForShutdown();
```

Comment: Instead of using `Console.ReadKey()` use `webHost.WaitForShutdown()`

Comment: You should use `int.Parse(address.Split(':').Last());` because the address could be defined as an IPv6 address

Comment: You can also use `webHost.RunAsync()` instead of `webHost.Start()` if you want to get the default messages printed in your console/output before you get the addresses.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do it in the StartUp.cs using the following code:

```
int Url = new System.Uri(Configuration["urls"]).Port;
```

Comment: This will not work if you listen on two ports (one for HTTP and another for HTTPS)

Comment: With .NET Core 3.1 `Configuration["urls"]` returns null in `Startup.Configure()` so this suggestion doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

At least from .Net Core 3 you can inject `IServer` and get the information.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Features;

namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    public class ServerInfoController : Controller
    {
        public ServerInfoController (IServer server)
        {
            var addresses = server.Features.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>()?.Addresses?.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an incomplete answer .. 

Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer'

Comment: @GabrielLuca It appears there may be issues with `IServer` not being registered if `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` isn't called. `ConfigureKestrel` does not register the `IServer` but `UseKestrel` and `CreateDefaultBuilder` do.

Comment: I called also called WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder and still not working ... I'll take back my down vote because ... it's strange how M$ changes things and something this simple is hard to .. get ..

I can't change my vote unless you change the answer ... it dose not allow me ..

Comment: if you can make it work .. post a small sample it will help ..

Comment: Using net7 with `WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)` this is working fine. And if you need `IServer` in StartUp, you can get it with `app.Services.GetRequiredService<IServer>()`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm able to do it using reflection (ugh!). I've registered an `IHostedService` and injected `IServer`. The `ListenOptions` property on `KestrelServerOptions` is internal, therefore I need to get to it using reflection. When the hosted service is called I then extract the port using the following code:

```
var options = ((KestrelServer)server).Options;
var propertyInfo = options.GetType().GetProperty("ListenOptions", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var listenOptions = (List<ListenOptions>)propertyInfo.GetValue(options);
var ipEndPoint = listenOptions.First().IPEndPoint;
var port = ipEndPoint.Port;
```