# Determine port Kestrel binded to

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, kestrel-http-server

I'm writing a simple ASP.NET Core service using ASP.NET Core empty (`web`) template.

By default, it binds to port 5000 but I would like it to bind to a random available port on the system.

I can do so by modifying `BuildWebHost` to:

```
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://*:0") // This enables binding to random port
            .Build();
```

It binds to a random port but how do I determine from within the application which port I'm listening to?

Comment: Run has an example of how to do this already built in: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/a63932a492513cdeb4935661145084cad2ae5521/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostExtensions.cs#L104

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hosting addresses of ASP.NET Core application could be accessed via `IServerAddressesFeature.Addresses` collection.

The main challenge is to invoke the code, which will analyze this collection, at the right time. The actual port binding happens when `IWebHost.Run()` is called (from `Program.Main()`). Therefore you can't yet access hosting address in `Startup.Configure()` method, because port has not been yet assigned on this stage. And you loose control after calling `IWebHost.Run()`, because this call does not return untill web host is shut down.

In my understanding, the most suitable way to analyze bound port is through implementation of [IHostedService](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-2-ihostedservice). Here is working sample:

```cs
public class GetBindingHostedService : IHostedService
{
    public static IServerAddressesFeature ServerAddresses { get; set; }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var address = ServerAddresses.Addresses.Single();
        var match = Regex.Match(address, @"^.+:(\d+)$");
        if (match.Success)
        {
            int port = Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
            Console.WriteLine($"Bound port is {port}");
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

In `Startup` class:

```cs
public class Startup
{

    //  ...

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, GetBindingHostedService>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();

        GetBindingHostedService.ServerAddresses = app.ServerFeatures.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>();
    }
}
```

Instance of `IServerAddressesFeature` is passed through ugly static property in `GetBindingHostedService`. I don't see other way how it could be injected into the service.

[**Sample Project on GitHub**](https://github.com/CodeFuller/stackoverflow/tree/Q49871318-Determine-Kestrel-Port)

Overall I'm not happy with such solution. It does the job, however it seems much more complex than it should be.

Comment: Worked for me. But I rather surprised you need to just through so many hoops to get such basic information.

Comment: Behavior seems to have changed with .NET Core 3.1. This solution leads to a NullReferenceException by the looks of it. When the singleton is created `StartAsync()` is correctly called but `ServerAddresses.Addresses` is empty.

Comment: In .Net Core 2, IHostedService was executed after the host starts so the server address information was readily available.  In .Net Core 3, IHostedService runs after the host is built, but before the host starts up and the address is no longer available.

[See here](https://andrewlock.net/running-async-tasks-on-app-startup-in-asp-net-core-3/)

Comment: You can inject an `IServer` and call `server.Features.GetFeature<IServerAddressFeature>()`

Answer (score 7):

You can call `IWebHost.Start()` instead of `IWebHost.Run()` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51822031/2464634).  This will allow execution of your `Main` method to continue so you can get the desired information from `IWebHost.ServerFeatures`.  Just remember, your application will shutdown immediately unless you explicitly tell it not to using `IWebHost.WaitForShutdown()`.

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://*:0") // This enables binding to random port
            .Build();

        host.Start();

        foreach(var address in host.ServerFeatures.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>().Addresses)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(address);
            var port = uri.Port;

            Console.WriteLine($"Bound to port: {port}");
        }

        //Tell the host to block the thread just as host.Run() would have.
        host.WaitForShutdown();
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a good way of doing it too - although it seems that `Run` is doing a few other things too.