# Get the Domain or Host name and Port in Configure of Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm in need of help in getting the host/domain name and port of my application.

So far, here's my sample code in my `Configure` method inside the `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var url = ""; // something that will get the current host/domain and port of the running applicaiton.

    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<ISomething>(i=>i.SomethingToExecute(url), Cron.Daily);
}
```

Because I need to pass the `url` string to my `SomethingToExecute` method

```
public class Something : ISomething 
{
    public void SomethingToExecute(string url){
        ... 
        Debug.WriteLine(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47051481/2251733

Comment: doesn't work to me bro

Comment: I think this might be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). It might help if you edit your question to explain why you are trying to do this? There may be better solutions to your problem than the way you are trying to solve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this [Github Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8101) and response from the ASP.NET Core team:

> It's not possible. You need to read this information directly from config. The server does not read the endpoint configuration until it's ready to start the application (after Startup). Even then, that information would be inaccurate much of the time due to reverse proxy setups like IIS, Nginx, docker, etc..

Comment: But is it possible to get the url inside the class not in startup.cs?

Comment: like get the url inside my `public void SomethingToExecute()`?

Comment: I hope it is possible.

Comment: I'm getting a null value in using `_httpContextAccessor` even after I already add it as singleton in my startup.cs

Comment: Yes! I am too because application is not started yet completely! Better you store the base url in `appsettings.json` file and retrieve from here or use hard coded.

Comment: are you getting `null` exemption in using `_httpContextAccessor` too sir?

Comment: Yes! I am also getting null reference exception. I have made the explanation in the previous comment.

Comment: I'm using hardcoded now which is not realible because if I need to redeploy the app in other machine, it's hassle if I need to republish the app because of changing the hardcoded link

Comment: That’s why you should store it in appsettings.json. You can change it easily from here after publish.

Answer (score 1):

It seems impossible but alternatively, if you want to invoke the HTTP Request or a Web API using C# Code, you can use `HttpClient()`

What you can do is combine what @TanvirArjel said and use `HttpClient()` to invoke the HTTP Request.

1. Store your host name in `appsettings.json`
2. In your `SomethingToExecute()` use something like this.

   ```
   private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
   public ISomething(IConfiguration configuration){
       this.configuration = configuration;
   }

   public void SomethingToExecute(){
       var httpClient = new HttpClient();

       var yourHostNameAndPort = configuration["NameFromYourAppSEttingsJsonFile"];

       httpClient.Get("" + yourHostNameAndPort + "...);
   }
   ```

I hope it helps somebody else too.

Answer (score 0):

As TanvirArjel already mentioned it seems impossible. But in your case you can dynamically get host name in your code body.

(Tested in .Net Core 2.1)

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    services.AddSingleton<something>();
}
```

**something.cs**

```
public class something
{
    public string url;

    public string SomethingToExecute()
    {
        return url;
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
[ApiController]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{

    private something _sth;

    public HomeController(something sth)
    {
        _sth = sth;
    }

    [HttpGet("foo")]
    public string foo()
    {

        _sth.url = Request.Scheme + "://" + Request.Host;
        return _sth.SomethingToExecute();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the host name - you can get easily it inside your controller by using Dns.GetHostName().
There is also another way is to get it from the HttpRequestContext like
Startup.cs => ConfigureServices => services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

Controler => ctor => use IHttpContextAccessor
and then in the controller methods

HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host
HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Port

However, HttpRequetsContext info is not very trustful.

Probably the best way to get host and port is discussed here already:
[Determine port Kestrel binded to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871318/determine-port-kestrel-binded-to)

Answer (score 0):

This alternative option may be useful, set the hostname in your appsettings.{Environment}.json and get the value through IConfiguration:

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration){
    _configuration = configuration;
}
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var host = _configuration.GetSection("Host").Get<string>();
}
```