# How to get host name in startup.cs in .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I want to get host name/address in .net core application to create connection string dynamically in the ConfigureServices. I have tried so many ways. How can i get the Request detail in startup.cs files

Comment: You cannot. Application startup happens only once, and long before any request has been received. In other words, there's no request to get information from.

Comment: By “host” do you mean the domain name of the web service? Or the name of the physical server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the Domain or Host name and Port in Configure of Startup.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369411/get-the-domain-or-host-name-and-port-in-configure-of-startup-cs)

Comment: @ChrisPratt you are correct. We can't use this in startup. I figure out another way full fill my requirement. Thanks a lot for saving my time.

Comment: @ChamaraNillushan could you please tell us what is your another way :)

Comment: Late to the party but this might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50496810/4477493

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
    public static string GetAddressIP()
    {
        return Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())
            .FirstOrDefault(ha => ha.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            .ToString();
    }
```